# applovin issue in get packagename manifest

Tags: android, applovin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ullw1.png)Applovin issue in manifest cannot get packagename

i wanna make applovin ads become something like admob no history, so when someone klik on applovin ads then back to my apps user no need to close the app
best regards

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sBiK.png)

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, package name can not contain upper case letters. You can check the format of package.